# Express.js - Postman error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smpt.mailtrap.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, token

I've been trying to generate a token to reset a user's password and send the user an email with the link to use that token.

This is the function ***forgotPassword*** defined in the class **authController**:

```
//forgot password  => /api/v1/password/forgot

exports.forgotPassword = catchAsynErrors(async(req, res, next) => {
    
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('User not found with this email', 404));
    }

    //get reset token
    const resetToken = user.getResetPasswordToken();
    await user.save({validateBeforeSave: false});

    // create reset password url
    const resetUrl = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/api/v1/password/reset/${resetToken}`;

    const message = `Your password reset token:\n\n${resetUrl}\n\n If you have not requested this email, please ignore it.`

    try {
        await sendEmail({
            email: user.email,
            subject: 'ShopIt password recovery',
            message 
        }) 

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: `Email sent to: ${user.email}`
        })

    } catch (error) {
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;
        
        await user.save({validateBeforeSave: false});
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500))
    }
})
```

Then, the function ***getResetPasswordToken*** defined in the *model* class **user**:

```
// generate password reset token
userSchema.methods.getResetPasswordToken = function() {
    //generate token
    const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');

    //hash and set to resetPasswordToken
    this.resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex')

    // set token expiration date
    this.resetPasswordExpire = Date.now() + 30 * 60 * 1000
    return resetToken

}
```

Upon sending a POST request via Postman to the URL `http://localhost:4000/api/v1/password/forgot` with the following JSON body,

```
{
"email": "example@email.com"
}
```

I get this response:

```
{
"success": false,
 error": {
    "statusCode": 500
},
"errMessage": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smpt.mailtrap.io",
"stack": "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND smpt.mailtrap.io\n    at D:\\pruebas de programación\\Proyectazo\\backend\\controllers\\authController.js:93:21\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"

}
```

I have seen suggestions that this could be a DNS error, but I have already tried manually setting up an IPv4 address like 192.168.1.45 and my DNS servers set to 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, and the internet worked normally but I kept getting the same error, so I set my network configuration back to DHCP. I also tried emailing both real and fake email addresses and it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which is line 93 of authController.js?

Comment: Hi, is the last line of ForgotPassword function                                                           return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500))

Comment: How is the `sendEmail` function defined?

Comment: const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const sendEmail = async options => {
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
       host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
       port: process.env.SMTP_PORT,
       auth: {
          user: process.env.SMTP_EMAIL,
          pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD
        }
      });
   const message = {
        from: `${process.env.SMTP_FROM_NAME} <${process.env.SMTP_FROM_EMAIL}>`,
        to: options.email,
        subject: options.subject,
        text: options.message
      }
await transporter.sendMail(message)
}
module.exports = sendEmail;